# Pyan3 installation instruction

Tags: function, call

Searching the web for a graphic tool to represent function and method call dependencies, it seems that Pyan3 is a good one, if not the only one.

I have not found the installation instructions in this Github link: https://github.com/davidfraser/pyan

Could someone help?

Answer (score 3):

Pyan3 maintainer here. [As of today, pyan3 is on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/pyan3/), so it can be installed via `pip install pyan3`. It installs a `pyan3` script to easily call it from the terminal.

The current situation is that [my repo](https://github.com/Technologicat/pyan) gets the latest developments and fixes for Pyan3 as long as I'm maintaining it, and changes are occasionally (but not very often) pushed to davidfraser's repo via a PR, when we both feel like dealing with one. Additionally, he's keeping the final version of Pyan2 archived with the tag `pre-python3`.

I think there are currently some bugfixes in my repo which have not yet been pushed, particularly with regard to compatibility with Python 3.6 and later.

If you run into problems with Pyan3, [please open an issue here](https://github.com/Technologicat/pyan/issues).

Answer (score 0):

Just clone the repo to install.

There is a 'visualize_pyan_architecture.sh' script you can look at for an example of how to run it. Within this, change the path to .py relative from where the script is located to try different .py files, you can have more than one and it will relate them in the graph produced. Beware trying *.py - I have found it can fail.

A little experimentation got me the results I wanted.

I found it best to export as .yed and use it's auto layout to make it readable. Then other layouts like orthogonal and radial really can give insight into complex projects.

If you use dot you may need to do something like:

```
sudo apt-get install graphviz
```

To get the dependencies.